# Internal kernel structures cannot be allocated error?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

When I run a program I've written, I get the following two error messages (multiple instances  of them infact). The program is quite big so can't show it here. Anyway, any idea what kind of programming error can cause these errors? Note that I'm using both `mmap` and `mprotect` in my program.

```
Internal kernel structures could not be allocated.
mprotect: Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: If you Google it, you'll find reference to it in the man page for `mprotect` under `ENOMEM`. How much memory are you trying to allocate, and how much do you have on the system?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are calling mprotect() on memory that you don't own. Eg., you might be calling mprotect() on memory that wasn't returned by mmap() or that has been unmapped with munmap().